# React MUI customizing Autocomplete's Popper component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'd like to customize the width of the Popper which comes with the Autocomplete component.
In my case the Autocomplete component it is placed inside a parent component, alongside a TextField.

Here the snippet on Codesandbox:

[image: Edit BasicTextFields Material Demo (forked)]

At the moment I have the following:
[image]

The parent component background color is set to green.

MY GOAL: **the Autocomplete Popper component should cover the entire green area**, in other words, the entire area delimited by the parent component (as consequence of this also the TextField).

**EDIT 1:** after Amr Eraky answer (solving the width problem)
[image]

**EDIT 2:**
So, the ***expected behaviour*** is the following (sorry for my poor graphic skills, I hope it is understandable anyway):

[image: Real expected behaviour]

So, we've got 2 problems here:

1. The width
2. The placement

As for the width I am able to set a custom width with the following code:

```
    const PopperMy = useCallback((props) => {
        return (<Popper {...props} style={{ width: 350 }} placement='right-end' />)
    },
 []);
```

But as you can see, this is not responsive and it is not even bound in some way to the width of the parent component, so this is not a good approach.

As for the placement, I'd like the popper to **overlap** its parent, but in the *placement* options I cannot find something like this, every option never allows the overlapping.

Could you please suggest a way to address these issues?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `anchorEl` prop of `Popper` to set the position of the popper.

> anchorEl :    Type of : HTML element | object | func
> An HTML element, virtualElement, or a function that returns either. It's used to set the position of the popper. The return value will passed as the reference object of the Popper instance.

You can get `anchorEl` of any element using `useRef`,
But because of your anchor element is in other component you can use `id`
And set height of `Popper` equal to `anchorEl`'s height.

```
const PopperMy = React.useCallback((props) => {
    const anchorEl = document.getElementById('new1');   // Or any other element
    return <Popper {...props} anchorEl={anchorEl} style={{ width: anchorEl.clientWidth }} placement='bottom' />;
}, []);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, your solution worked like a charm!
Actually I noticed that the "expected behaviour" image I posted was incomplete, so I edited it. I meant, also the Autocomplete component width should follow its container, but only when clicked (as in the new image). Is there a way to fix also this?
Thanks again.

Comment: Use props `open`, `setOpen` and `onClose`, Please Check the Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/basictextfields-material-demo-forked-z3mlee?file=/demo.js